# Proof of $\pi+e$ irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Open_questions/) tells that it is not known that $\pi+e$ is irrational? 
Immediately after reading this my mind came with this proof- 
Let $x =\sqrt{\pi^2}+\sqrt{e^2}$  be rational, then
$  \quad (x-\sqrt{\pi^2})^2=\sqrt{e^2}$ is rational , now
$\quad x^2-2x\sqrt{\pi^2}-\pi^2=e^2$ is rational , now 
$\quad \frac{e^2-x^2-\pi^2}{-2x} = \sqrt{\pi^2}=\pi$ is rational.
This is a contradiction as $\pi$ is irrational! Thus we prove by contradiction that $\pi+e $ is irrational.

Please tell me me if this is a valid proof? And also tell my mistake if I am wrong somewhere?

Comment: The second line $\left(x-\sqrt{\pi^2}\right)^2=\sqrt{e^2}$ is rational is nonsensical. How do you conclude that? If you could conclude that, you'd be done.

Comment: Your "proof" is invalid. I'm pretty sure what you are trying to prove is still an open problem. Please do a simple google search before posting here.

Comment: Is there a typo in the second step?  If $x = \sqrt{\pi^2} + \sqrt{e^2}$ then $(x-\sqrt{\pi^2})^2 = e^2$.  And how does it follow that this is rational?

Comment: Also, in the second equation, you subtract $\pi$ from both sides and square, but you forget to square the right-hand side (you corrected this in the third line). Also, note that $x$ is rational, so we must have $x-\pi$ is irrational. We cannot say that $(x-\pi)^2$ is rational. In the last line, you should have a $+\pi^2$ instead of $-\pi^2$. Unfortunately, you have several mistakes in your attempt.

Comment: What's with the serial downvoting and voting to close on a perfectly sincere question which shows research effort?

Comment: Maybe people here do not accept mistakes.

Comment: This post has $31$ upvotes and $24$ downvotes as of this comments posting

Comment: I am adding a final close vote to this question, as I do not feel that these kinds of questions are appropriate for Math SE.  Math SE is not meant as a place to publish new mathematical results, nor to ask for critiques or criticism of purported solutions to open problems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is nonsense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not really a good fit for math.se

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's not clear how you can deduce the first step of your proof.

Let $a=\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $b=2-\sqrt[4]{2}$. Then from:

$$2=a+b$$

can we conclude that:

$$(2-b)^2=a^2=\sqrt{2}$$ is rational?

It's certainly the case that $(2-b)^2=a^2$. But why is it rational?